# Where is the default collectd pluggindir?

Tags: collectd

Where does Collectd store its plugins by default? I am missing a perl plugin and I want to make sure its not because the installation was hosed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin location is configured using the directive `PluginDir` in `collectd.conf`.
The default (compiled in) location can be queried using the builtin help:

```
$ collectd -h
Usage: collectd [OPTIONS]
[...]
Builtin defaults:
[...]
Plugin directory  /usr/lib/collectd
[...]
```

This is for the plugins written in C. You are referring to a perl plugin, so this applies to `perl.so`, which is the perl interpreter plugin itself. If you were asking about the location of the perl (`*.pm`) files, then it's your perl policies that apply (i.e. `@INC`). If you need to force the standard perl module location, you can use the `IncludeDir` directive inside your `<Plugin perl>` block

Answer (score 4):

On my system (Fedora 17) the plugins are installed in /usr/lib64/collectd, from the following packages:

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/collectd/* | sort -u
collectd-4.10.8-2.fc17.x86_64
collectd-rrdtool-4.10.8-2.fc17.x86_64
collectd-sensors-4.10.8-2.fc17.x86_64
collectd-snmp-4.10.8-2.fc17.x86_64
$
```